# The instagram-ruby-gem excludes capitalized hashtags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems, instagram, capitalization

Basically, `Instagram.tag_recent_media("hashtag")` will return images that contain `#hashtag` but not `#Hashtag`. This is not how the API functions. Searches done within the Instagram API console are case insensitive and return all expected results.

I think this is a bug in the `instagram-ruby-gem` but I wanted to make sure. I've already flagged the issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/issues/127

Has anyone else had this experience? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out what was going on here. The user who had the capitalized hashtag was ALSO a private user, and thus not showing up in anonymous API results. False alarm. Ruby gem most likely works correctly.